# Python: __qualname__ of function with decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I'm using a Decorator (class) in an Instance method of another class, like this:

```
class decorator_with_arguments(object):

    def __init__(self, arg1=0, arg2=0, arg3=0):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.arg3 = arg3

    def __call__(self, f):
        print("Inside __call__()")
        def wrapped_f(*args):
            print(f.__qualname__)
            f(*args)
        return wrapped_f

class Lol:
    @decorator_with_arguments("hello")
    def sayHello(self,a1, a2, a3, a4):
        print(self.sayHello.__qualname__)
```

Now, when I print out `self.sayHello.__qualname__` it prints `decorator_with_arguments.__call__.<locals>.wrapped_f`

Is there any way to override this? I want to see `Lol.sayHello` (**qualname** of my original function) in here.

I tried overriding the `@property` `__qualname__` of `__call__` (with a static string); didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply copy the `__qualname__` attribute across to your *`wrapped_f` wrapper function*; it is this function that is returned when the decorator is applied, after all.

You could use the [`@functools.wraps()` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to do this for you, together with other attributes of note:

```
from functools import wraps

class decorator_with_arguments(object): 
    def __init__(self, arg1=0, arg2=0, arg3=0):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.arg3 = arg3

    def __call__(self, f):
        print("Inside __call__()")
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped_f(*args):
            print(f.__qualname__)
            f(*args)
        return wrapped_f
```

The `@wraps(f)` decorator there copies the relevant attributes from `f` onto `wrapped_f`, including `__qualname__`:

```
>>> Lol.sayHello.__qualname__
'Lol.sayHello'
```