# Python how to get __qualname__ of method wrapped with property.setter

Tags: python, properties, python-decorators, descriptor, python-descriptors

I have an instance attribute that I made a property using Python's `property` decorator.

I then made a setter for the property using the decorator `@property_name.setter`.

How can I get the `__qualname__` of the original method definition, decorated with `@property.setter`?

---

**Where I Have Looked**

- [Python: __qualname__ of function with decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50815820/11163122)

  - I don't think `property` uses `@functools.wraps()`
- [Python @property.setter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23246400/11163122)

  - I realize `property` is actually a `descriptor`
- [Decorating a class method after @property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4923706/11163122)

  - Tells me I may want to use `__get__`, but I can't figure out the syntax

---

**Example Code**

This was written in `Python 3.6`.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3


def print_qualname():
    """Wraps a method, printing its qualified name."""

    def print_qualname_decorator(func):
        # print(f"func = {func} and dir(): {dir(func)}")
        if hasattr(func, "__qualname__"):
            print(f"Qualified name = {func.__qualname__}.")
        else:
            print("Doesn't have qualified name.")

    return print_qualname_decorator


class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self._some_attr = 0
        self._another_attr = 0

    @property
    def some_attr(self) -> int:
        return self._some_attr

    @print_qualname()
    @some_attr.setter
    def some_attr(self, val: int) -> None:
        self._some_attr = val

    @print_qualname()
    def get_another_attr(self) -> int:
        return self._another_attr
```

Output:

```
Doesn't have qualified name.
Qualified name = SomeClass.get_another_attr.
```

How can I get the `__qualname__` for `some_attr` from inside the `print_qualname` decorator?  In other words, how do I get `SomeClass.some_attr` to be output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could flip the ordering of the decorators for the setter. Note I've adjusted the `print_qualname_decorator` to call the underlying function and return it (otherwise the setter will not execute).

```
from functools import wraps

def print_qualname(func):
    """Wraps a method, printing its qualified name."""
    @wraps(func)
    def print_qualname_decorator(*args):
        if hasattr(func, "__qualname__"):
            print(f"Qualified name = {func.__qualname__}.")
        else:
            print("Doesn't have qualified name.")
        return func(*args)
    return print_qualname_decorator


class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self._some_attr = 0
        self._another_attr = 0

    @property
    def some_attr(self) -> int:
        return self._some_attr

    @some_attr.setter
    @print_qualname
    def some_attr(self, val: int) -> None:
        self._some_attr = val

    @print_qualname
    def get_another_attr(self) -> int:
        return self._another_attr
```

Use

```
In [46]: foo = SomeClass()                                               

In [47]: foo.get_another_attr()                                          
Qualified name = SomeClass.get_another_attr.
Out[47]: 0

In [48]: foo.some_attr = 5                                               
Qualified name = SomeClass.some_attr.

In [49]: foo._some_attr                                                  
Out[49]: 5
```

Comment: Thank you @KentShikama!  I had not thought of that